# Knife edit node

Tags: chef-infra, knife

knife edit node gives an error message:

```
ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'node' when current directory is outside the repository path
```

I really don't understand in what folder should I execute this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want `knife node edit` here, rather than `knife edit node`. In that case, you can be anywhere in the chef-repo.

Comment: Thx a lot. Such a silly mistake and took such time =|